# Azure DataBricks To Connect SQL DataBase with Pyspark

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, azure-databricks

I would like to connect SQL Server from azure databricks notebook, we have to use AD integrated authentication with python code. could you please help me, how to establish connect the SQL DB tables.

Note : we have not permission any scale access, we have to use only python or SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Azure SQL Database, you will need to install the `SQL Spark Connector` and the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication Library for Python. Go to your cluster in Data bricks and Install `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha` from Maven And `axal` from `PyPI`.

Comment: could you please provide the connection code if possible, mean while, i can connect with my databricks admin

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect Azure sql database with Azure active directory Integrated authentication I faced below error:

```
Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

As per [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/raising-the-baseline-security-for-all-organizations-in-the-world/ba-p/3299048) MFA is the default method of login for all azure tenants. Hence, I used `ActiveDirectoryInteractive` instead of `ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` to conform to MFA standards I got below error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user x-xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive). Unable to open default system browser
```

[image]

I sort this out with below workaround:
I installed below libraries in my cluster:

[image]

I created service principal and generated secret, and I logged in as admin and created service principal user and added roles to the user with below code:

```
create user [<servicePrincipelName>] from external provider
alter add role db_owner add member [<servicePrincipelName>]
```

I have taken below values from service principal:

- `tenant_id`,
- `client ID`,
- `service_principal_secret`

I have used below code to connect SQL database:

```
import adal
tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"
authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_id
resource_app_id_url = "https://database.windows.net/"
service_principal_id = "<client ID>
service_principal_secret = "<servicePrincipalSecret>"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.database.windows.net"
database_name = "<databaseName>"
db_table = "dbo.<tableName>" 
encrypt = "true"
host_name_in_certificate = "*.database.windows.net"
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_app_id_url, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret)
access_token = token["accessToken"]
user = "<Activedirectory User>"
password = "<AD password>"
jdbc_df = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
              .option("url", url) \
              .option("dbtable", db_table) \
              .option("accessToken", access_token) \
              .option("encrypt", encrypt) \
              .option("databaseName", database_name) \
              .option("hostNameInCertificate", host_name_in_certificate) \
              .load() 

display(jdbc_df.select("Name").limit(1))
```

It connected to the database and retrieved the data from database table according to the query:

[image]